# PHP NuSOAP response

Tags: php, response, nusoap

Is it normal that the response of the nusoap server is like this?

If not, how do i fix or remove the `&lt` and `&gt` and make it as `<` and `>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:get_stocksResponse xmlns:ns1="VSR"><return xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;facilitator&gt;
&lt;stock_response&gt;
    &lt;product&gt;
      &lt;productid&gt;1072722&lt;/productid&gt;
      &lt;voorraad&gt;888040&lt;/voorraad&gt;
    &lt;/product&gt;
    &lt;product&gt;
      &lt;productid&gt;1072724&lt;/productid&gt;
      &lt;voorraad&gt;888603&lt;/voorraad&gt;
    &lt;/product&gt;
&lt;/stock_response&gt;
&lt;/facilitator&gt;
</return></ns1:get_stocksResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope></code>
```

this is my register function in the server

```
$this->server->register('get_stocks',                // method name
        array('product' => 'xsd:int'),        // input parameters
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'),      // output parameters
        $this->_namespace,                      // namespace
        'urn:'.$this->_namespace.'#get_stocks',                // soapaction
        'rpc',                                // style
        'encoded',                            // use
        'Get stocks of products'            // documentation
    );
```

and this is my return function

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xmlDoc->formatOutput = TRUE;
...etc
$nodes = $xmlDoc -> getElementsByTagName ('facilitator');
$node = $nodes -> item(0);

return $xmlDoc->saveXML($node);
```

Comment: You are returning escaped XML inside an XML document: `<return xsi:type="xsd:string">` - the escaped **string** is a `String`, not an XML structure. You have implemented it wrong I guess.

Comment: then what should it be? thanks

Comment: checkout your character encoding ! Your return XML is encoding="ISO-8859-1" but your return function is utf-8

Comment: i fixed the encoding but still not fixed the issue, thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from this [Nusoap use existing WSDL how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316743/nusoap-use-existing-wsdl-how-to)

i found this

```
var $methodreturnisliteralxml = false;
```

and just set it to true upon creating the nusoap server

```
$this->server->methodreturnisliteralxml = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array('return' => 'xsd:string')
```

the output is a **string**, not xml-structure. Strings inside XML must be encoded. If you want to return other data you have to use a `ComplexType`. Look at this question: [PHP Web Service NuSOAP complex type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001916/php-web-service-nusoap-complex-type)

Example:

```
$this->server->wsdl->addComplexType(/** definition **/);


$this->server->register('get_stocks',              // method name
    array('product' => 'xsd:int'),                 // input parameters
    array('return' => 'tns:yourComplexType'),      // output parameters
```

Like @butching said, you also have an encoding mismatch, which is bad but not the cause for your issue.

Comment: the problem with using complextype, the result is array not xml